# how to predict x given y for nls model?

Tags: r, nls, uniroot

I am using the nls SSlogis function in R to make a model expressing water absorption in a plant, where y=water absorption (g per m^2), and x=minutes in water. For a given y value (in this case max water absorption), I would like to solve for x (the minute we reach peak absorption) using each model (I have a few species each with an individual model).

I have tried the uniroot() function, but I seem to be doing it wrong:

```
mod1_roots <- uniroot(mod1, lower=0, upper=600, y=max_y_mod1)
```

where lower and upper are the range of minutes, and mod1 is the SSlogis model in question

The error message is: `Error in f(lower, ...) : could not find function "f"`

So I assume I am not using the "function" part correctly and it should be something other than the model. Ugh.

Can anyone help a clueless botanist out? Thanks friends!

Edit for reproducibility (I hope):

Here's some real data

```
absorption <- c(297.0470936,262.809483,323.8243166,296.6731868,313.5985664,283.1004567,259.8724386,228.8903642,197.1585476,230.1674857,182.5799195,148.0262402,134.087096,77.98206413)

minutes <- c(195,181,167,157,147,135,105,83,63,45,33,24,10)

cembra <- as.data.frame(cbind(absorption,minutes))

cembra_mod <- nls(absorption ~ SSlogis(minutes, Asym, xmid, scal), cembra)
```

My goal is to predict the minutes at which absorption = 100 (or any specified number). Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying, but if you want to revert SSlogis(x, a,b,c..) then the function should be `function(x) SSlogis(x, a,b,c...)` instead mod (despite logistic being analytically invertible).

Comment: Thanks @RicVillalba ! I may have misunderstood, but when I try with real values:   'mod1_roots <- uniroot(function(x) SSlogis(x, 205.569308 , -6.008204 , 84.069670 ), lower=0, upper=600, y=0.610389630515968)'   Then I get the error: 'Error in f(lower, ...) : unused argument (y = 0.610389630515968)'

Comment: `y` is not a parameter of neither uniroot nor sslogis.

Answer (score 1):

When posting to SO please provide a complete self contained reproducible example that others can run to reproduce the problem.  We will provide a reproducible example for you this time to show how it is done.  `ChickWeight` below comes with R.  This shows how to find what  `Time` corresponds to a `weight` of 200 assuming that the value is within the range of the input `Time` values. The fact that the objective in the output is zero shows that it worked.

```
Chick.1 <- ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick == 1, ]
fm <- nls(weight ~ SSlogis(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), Chick.1)
pred <- function(x) predict(fm, list(Time = x))
optimize(function(x) (pred(x) - 200)^2, range(Chick.1$Time))
```

giving:

```
$minimum
[1] 20.34701

$objective
[1] 2.498361e-08
attr(,"gradient")
          Asym      xmid     scal
[1,] 0.2134402 -13.79298 17.99035
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience @G.Grothendieck ! I edited my question to be reproducible. My goal is to predict minutes when a given level of absorption is attained. Sorry for the confusion, I'm a new user of this forum